# Losing focus on DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, focus

I am manually setting the focus on DataGrid to one of its cells in the `RowEditEnding` event handler by writing

```
cell.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(cell);
```

after this I test if it worked by calling

```
Debug.WriteLine(cell.IsFocused);
Debug.WriteLine(cell.IsKeyboardFocused);
```

and it prints `True` and `True`, so the focus goes to the cell as needed.

The problem is that immediately after that the focus goes away to containing `ScrollViewer` or some other container.

What is the reason for such a behavior? How can I fix that?